# Why is it called the No-Arbitrage Theorem if it’s really “arbitrage exists but only briefly”?

Tags: arbitrage, no-arbitrage-theory, terminology

Why is it called the No-Arbitrage Theorem if it’s really “arbitrage exists but only briefly”? Is it just because all opportunities revert to equilibrium so fast that there’s no *ultimate* arbitrage, or is there a deeper meaning?

Comment: Theory is about models = approximations of reality. In reality, arbitrage strategies may exist but only briefly. In most theoretical models, arbitrage never exists. The absence of arbitrage is necessary (but not sufficient) for an equilibrium to exist.

Comment: I don't see how this is off-topic or why the question was closed...

Comment: Then you should vote to reopen

Comment: In the continuous time framework, there is indeed no arbitrage. However, in the context of trading, continuous time is a (useful) fiction.